# Azure application insights drops some custom events

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a Web Application and want to track user logins in AppInsights with the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        var success = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(model);

        _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Login",
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "UserName", model.UserName },
                { "UsingPin", model.UsingPin.ToString()},
                { "ReturnUrl", returnUrl},
                { "LastUsedUrl", model.LastUsedUrl },
                { "Success", success.ToString() }
            });

         return View(model);
    }
```

The code works, I get events in analytics portal... but only a subset of events! In the sessions table on the database side I have about 1000 unique user logins, but AI reports around 100...

What I have already checked:

1. _telemetryClient is a singleton configured through Unity (`<lifetime type="singleton" />`)
2. there is no quota configured in Azure portal
3. I have more than 1000 POST requests to the Login method, this looks just right (I mean every request comes to this exact server, returns 200 status, etc.)

So it looks like Azure just drops some of custom events... or they are not send to azure for some reason. Is there any configuration part I am missing?

Comment: The TelemetryClient send data to Azure in Batches, you can try to flush the buffer using `_telemetryClient.Flush();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if your application sends a lot of data and you are using the Application Insights SDK for ASP.NET version 2.0.0-beta3 or later, the adaptive sampling feature may operate and send only a percentage of your telemetry.

So I guess this the reason why you just see 100 records in the AI.

If you want to send all the records to the AI, I suggest you could disable the adaptive sampling. More details about how to disable the adaptive sampling, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling#fixed-rate-sampling-for-aspnet-web-sites).

Notice: This is not recommended. Sampling is designed so that related telemetry is correctly transmitted, for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: This arcticle was very helpful. According to it I have around 10% of total events logged on Application Insights. Unfortunatelly I cannot reproduce it locally, where rhousands of reuqests are successfully logged to AI... Another issue I currently face is that we have 2 servers (one for users and one for internal testing) with same InstrumentationKey. And no matter where I send requests, they are not shown in the AI. This is very strage, because testing server does not experience any load at all and should log everything... Based on this fact I think the bottleneck is somewhere on Azure side

Comment: As far as I know, adaptive sampling doesn't operate at low volumes of telemetry, so an app in debugging or a website with low usage won't be affected.

Comment: Based on my test, if you set the right InstrumentationKey and enable the AI in the right way, it will send the trace information to the azure. If this doesn' work, I suggest you could follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data) to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I have been using .Net 4.5, after updating to 4.6.2, updating Application Insights packages and configuring everything as specified in the article you have referenced - now I have 100% custom events logged. Thank you!

Comment: if that's the case, do you recommend against using AI for logging, since we actually want EVERYTHING logged, not just a sample